# Script to detect if USB drive has been blocked

Tags: powershell

USB is blocked by AD. I need to perform an audit to check the systems USB drive. Is there any way in powershell that i can run the script on the systems/remotely but not from AD and know their removable storage policy- whether blocked or not.

Thanx in advance 
Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex question, so I can only provide pointers: assuming we are talking about a Group Policy-based removable disk blocking, you can use `gpresult` of Windows to retrieve information about the policy currently in effect. Specifically, `gpresult /SCOPE computer /X report.xml` will give you a detailed XML report about the effective policy for the local system. You can manipulate XML files with ease in PowerShell. Running PowerShell remotely is also a non-issue using `Invoke-Command`.

GPResult:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160.aspx

PowerShell and XML:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/13/use-powershell-to-simplify-access-to-xml-data.aspx

Invoke-Command:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx